# akka.pattern.after: Memory Leak

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, akka, thread-dump

Following piece of code causes memory leak for my play Scala web service. When i take threadDump i notice that PluginTimeout thread is waiting all the time and never gets executed.

```
  override final def execute:Future[Any] = {
    val f1 = executePlugin // this returns a future

    val system = ActorSystem("PluginTimeout")
    val timeoutFuture = akka.pattern.after(timeout, system.scheduler) { throw new TimeoutException(s"{$name} timed out")  }
    Future.firstCompletedOf(f1 :: timeoutFuture :: Nil)
  }
```

This is what my thread dump looks like. After taking several threa dump i noticed that the number of PlugintTimeout objects keeps increasing in each subsequent thread dump.

```
"PluginTimeout-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2" #2308 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fa02c84f800 nid=0x88707 waiting on condition [0x00000001803a3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000007ab6f5d68> (a akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinPool)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"PluginTimeout-scheduler-1" #2307 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fa02b34f800 nid=0x80f07 sleeping[0x000000017f16d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.waitNanos(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:81)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:260)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:230)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

If i remove the the Future timeout logic from my method, i don not see any issues with memory leak. What might be going on here. One possible explanation is that timeoutFuture never gets executed, if the other future succeeds and keeps waiting for eternity. This causes several futures to stack up and hog memory. Any clues on whats going on?

Comment: ActorSystem is a heavyweight object, and you create One for each innovation and do not shut it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a lot of ActorSystems (`n` systems for `n` execute calls).

An ActorSystem is rather heavy as it contains configuration ThreadPools etc.

You should instead use `1` ActorSystem and use it in your logic. 
For example by passing it in implicitly: `def execute()(implicit system: ActorSystem)`